# how to do it better replace continueWith to async/await in C#

Tags: c#, async-await, task, token, continuewith

I have `C#` code:

```
public class SimpleClass{

    public Task<TestClass> WaitForUserInput(IResource resource, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var button = resource.GetResource();

        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<UserActionResult>();
        IDisposable cancellationTokenReg = token.Register(
                                      () => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(new TestClass()));

        var taskDisposeTokenUnreg = taskCompletionSource.Task.ContinueWith(
            task =>
                {
                    cancellationTokenReg.Dispose();
                     return task.Result;
                 });

        button.TouchEvent += Subscribe;
        button.Disabled = true;

        return taskDisposeTokenUnreg;
    }
}
```

I need replace `continueWith` to `await`. And I try in this example:

```
public class SimpleClass{

    public async Task<TestClass> WaitForUserInput(IResource resource, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var button = resource.GetResource();

        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<UserActionResult>();
        IDisposable cancellationTokenReg = token.Register(
                                      () => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(new TestClass()));

        var taskDisposeTokenUnreg = await taskCompletionSource.Task
        cancellationTokenReg.Dispose();
        return taskDisposeTokenUnreg.Result;

        button.TouchEvent += Subscribe;
        button.Disabled = true;

        return taskDisposeTokenUnreg;
    }
}
```

But `taskDisposeTokenUnreg` has no field `Result` and and you can’t write like that `await taskCompletionSource.Task.Result`.
How best to replace this code?

Comment: `var taskDisposeTokenUnreg` should already be the `Result` - did you check what type it has?

Answer (score 1):

When you use the [`await` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) on a `Task`, the value you get is the result of the `Task`.

So in your case, `taskDisposeTokenUnreg` will already be the `UserActionResult` value you are looking for. You can just `return taskDisposeTokenUnreg`.

Answer (score 0):

Your original method has a synchronous signature; all the code in that method (except the delegates) is executed immediately. The `ContinueWith` delegate is the only code that executes *later*, after the `taskCompletionSource.Task` completes. So, to duplicate this behavior, you need to move the `ContinueWith` delegate to the *end* of the method, so all the synchronous code executes first just like it did before:

```
public async Task<TestClass> WaitForUserInput(IResource resource, CancellationToken token)
{
  var button = resource.GetResource();

  var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<UserActionResult>();
  IDisposable cancellationTokenReg = token.Register(
                                      () => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(new TestClass()));

  button.TouchEvent += Subscribe;
  button.Disabled = true;

  var result = await taskCompletionSource.Task;
  cancellationTokenReg.Dispose();
  return result;
}
```

Once you're using `async`/`await`, then you can simplify further by using a `using` declaration:

```
public async Task<TestClass> WaitForUserInput(IResource resource, CancellationToken token)
{
  var button = resource.GetResource();

  var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<UserActionResult>();
  using var cancellationTokenReg = token.Register(
                                      () => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(new TestClass()));

  button.TouchEvent += Subscribe;
  button.Disabled = true;

  return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```